# Eclipse Migration and org.eclipse.ui.internal apis

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am currently migrating a very old piece of code written in Eclipse Helios to Eclipse Mars. The code makes use of certain apis from `org.eclipse.ui.internal` package such as `EditorSashContainer`, `EditorStack`, `PartStack`, `LayoutPart` etc. Is it that these apis are no longer available in e4 compatibility layer? Or do I need to import few more plugins? What would be the best approach to migrate the code which might involve minimal code changes. We are using these apis to basically spilt the editor so that it gives a workbook kind of look.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet how I split the editor in the E4 environment.

This is how I execute: `splitEditor(0.5f, 3, currentEditor, newEditor)`

```
@Override
public void splitEditor(float ratio, int where, IEditorPart containerEditor, IEditorPart editorToInsert) {
    MPart container = containerEditor.getSite().getService(MPart.class);
    if (container == null) {
        return;
    }
    MPart toInsert = editorToInsert.getSite().getService(MPart.class);
    if (toInsert == null) {
        return;
    }

    insertEditor(ratio, where, container, toInsert);
}

/**
 * Inserts the editor into the container editor.
 *
 * @param ratio the ratio
 * @param where where to insert ({@link EModelService#LEFT_OF}, {@link EModelService#RIGHT_OF}, {@link EModelService#ABOVE} or
 * {@link EModelService#BELOW})
 * @param containerEditor the container editor
 * @param editorToInsert the editor to insert
 */
public void insertEditor(float ratio, int where, MPart containerEditor, MPart editorToInsert) {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    EModelService service = window.getService(EModelService.class);
    MPartStack toInsert = getPartStack(editorToInsert);

    MArea area = getArea(containerEditor);
    MPartSashContainerElement relToElement = area.getChildren().get(0);
    service.insert(toInsert, relToElement, where, ratio);
}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
private MPartStack getPartStack(MPart childPart) {
    MStackElement stackElement = childPart;
    MPartStack newStack = org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.BasicFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createPartStack();
    newStack.getChildren().add(stackElement);
    newStack.setSelectedElement(stackElement);
    return newStack;
}

private MArea getArea(MPart containerPart) {
    MUIElement targetParent = containerPart.getParent();
    while (!(targetParent instanceof MArea)) {
        targetParent = targetParent.getParent();
    }
    MArea area = (MArea) targetParent;
    return area;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using internal APIs [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

The internals of Eclipse were completely rewritten for Eclipse 4 and many internal interface were changed or removed. Everything is now based around the EMF model representing the objects in the GUI. A compatibility layer provides the old style APIs but this only supports the official APIs.

There is no straightforward way to deal with the changes to the internal APIs. You are going to have to understand the new way Eclipse does things.

You can override the 'renderers' for most components such as part stacks which might be a way to do what you want.